# Hybrid Active Directory Query

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, active-directory

I am trying to create a hybrid Active Directory / SQL Server table query. Here is what I have so far:

```
declare @openQry varchar(500) = '
(SELECT 
    EC.EmpNo AS [Emp ID]
    ,EC.FirstName AS [First Name]
    ,EC.LastName AS [Last Name]
    ,sAMAccountName AS [AD Username]
    ,EC.KronosUsername AS [Kronos     Username]
FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI,''
    SELECT sAMAccountName
    FROM ''''LDAP://int.chickasaw.net'''' 
    WHERE objectClass = ''''person'''' ''),
    [EnterpriseUtility].[dbo].[Employee_Cache] EC
 WHERE sAMAccountName <> EC.KronosUsername
     AND EC.EmployeeStatus = ''Active''
)'
exec (@openQry)
```

This is the error that I am getting when I try to execute the query.

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Emp'.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Why are you wrapping this whole thing in dynamic sql? I would start by removing that portion as it is doing nothing but adding an extra layer.

Comment: I am trying to adjust an existing sproc that requires the user to enter an employee id to get the AD information. I want it to get information based off of employee id's found in another table.

Comment: `declare @EmployeeID INT = 60580
                                        
declare @openQry varchar(500) = 'SELECT sAMAccountName, mail, telephoneNumber FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI,''SELECT sAMAccountName, mail, telephoneNumber FROM ''''LDAP://int.chickasaw.net'''' WHERE objectClass = ''''person'''' AND employeeID = ''''' + convert(varchar(10),@EmployeeID) +''''' '')'
exec (@openQry)`

Comment: Without some context here there is little anybody can do to help. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/